# async / await - am I correctly running these methods in parallel?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have an abstract class called `VehicleInfoFetcher` which returns information asynchronously from a `WebClient` via this method:

```
public override async Task<DTOrealtimeinfo> getVehicleInfo(string stopID);
```

I'd like to combine the results of two separate instances of this class, running each in parallel before combining the results.  This is done within a third class, `CombinedVehicleInfoFetcher` (also itself a subclass of `VehicleInfoFetcher`)

Here's my code - but I'm not quite convinced that it's running the tasks in parallel; am I doing it right?  Could it be optimized?

```
 public class CombinedVehicleInfoFetcher : VehicleInfoFetcher
    {
        public HashSet<VehicleInfoFetcher> VehicleInfoFetchers { get; set; }

        public override async Task<DTOrealtimeinfo> getVehicleInfo(string stopID)
        {
            // Create a list of parallel tasks to run
            var resultTasks = new List<Task<DTOrealtimeinfo>>();
            foreach (VehicleInfoFetcher fetcher in VehicleInfoFetchers)
                resultTasks.Add(fetcher.getVehicleInfo(stopID, stopID2, timePointLocal));

            // run each task
            foreach (var task in resultTasks)
                await task;

            // Wait for all the results to come in
            await Task.WhenAll(resultTasks.ToArray());

            // combine the results
            var allRealtimeResults = new List<DTOrealtimeinfo>( resultTasks.Select(t => t.Result)  );
            return combineTaskResults(allRealtimeResults);
        }

        DTOrealtimeinfo combineTaskResults(List<DTOrealtimeinfo> realtimeResults)
        {
             // ...


            return rtInfoOutput;
        }

    }
```

**Edit**

Some very helpful answers, here is a re-written example to aid discussion with usr below:

```
       public override async Task<object> combineResults()
        {
            // Create a list of parallel tasks to run
            var resultTasks= new List<object>();
            foreach (AnotherClass cls in this.OtherClasses)
                resultTasks.Add(cls.getResults() );

            // Point A - have the cls.getResults() methods been called yet?

            // Wait for all the results to come in
            await Task.WhenAll(resultTasks.ToArray());

            // combine the results
             return new List<object>( resultTasks.Select(t => t.Result)  );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all tasks start out already started. Probably, whatever `fetcher.getVehicleInfo` returns is already started. So you can remove:

```
        // run each task
        foreach (var task in resultTasks)
            await task;
```

`Task.WhenAll` is faster and has better error behavior (you want all exceptions to be propagated, not just the first you happen to stumble upon).

Also, await does not start a task. It waits for completion. You have to arrange for the tasks to be started separately, but as I said, almost all tasks are already started when you get them. This is best-practice as well.

---

To help our discussion in the comments:

```
Task Test1() { return new Task(() => {}); }
Task Test2() { return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {}); }
Task Test3() { return new FileStream("").ReadAsync(...); }
Task Test4() { return new TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task; }
```

1. Does not "run" when returned from the method. Must be started. Bad practice.
2. Runs when returned. Does not matter what you do with it, it is already running. Not necessary to add it to a list or store it somewhere.
3. Already runs like (2).
4. The notion of running does not make sense here. This task will never complete although it cannot be explicitly started.

Comment: I'm still confused.  You say that `await` doesn't start Tasks, but if I was to put the single line `await getVehicleInfo("foo");` this would start the task, right?

Comment: No, the task was already started. await would then only continue execution once the task was done. Try this: `await new TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task`. This will never complete because the task never finishes.; Sidenote: await does not introduce concurrency/threads. Maybe this is the misundestanding you're having? All it does is "logically wait" for completion.

Comment: If you don't say `await` the task will still run concurrently.

Comment: OK, but if I remove the lines you suggest, then at what point in code execution are the (child) `getVehicleInfo` methods called?  Is it when they're added to `resultTasks` or is it at `Task.WhenAll` ?

Comment: Inside(!) of `fetcher.getVehicleInfo` (you can post the source and I'll tell you exactly). I repeat: the task is already running when this method returns. `Task.WhenAll` just waits for completion.

Comment: I think you misunderstand - it doesn't help that all the method names are the same!  I've added example code to the bottom of my question.  When are the parallel tasks started - at Point (A) in the example code, or at `Task.WhenAll()` ?

Comment: Never mind, I just tested it - your answer is correct, and the answer to my question in the comments above is that the Tasks **are** started merely by adding them to the `List<Task<...>>` - I guess the method is just called inline; I wondered if that might be the case.

Comment: Glad I helped you but I think there is still one misunderstanding: The list has nothing to do with starting the tasks. You seem not to be able to accept the notion that you do not have to start the task yourself... Not sure why.

Comment: I do 'get it', I think maybe I'm just using the wrong semantics so there's a communication error between us.  What I'm trying to say is that if I declare a good old-fashioned delegate that points to a method, this in itself does not call the method.  However, adding a method that returns a `Task<..>` to a `List<Task<...>>` **does** call the method.  Does that communicate effectively to you what I mean?

Comment: The method gets called, but the method call itself is independent from the task that it returns. I edited in 4 different methods that all return different kinds of tasks. Whether they are running or not, whether they can be "started" or not, depends not on the method call itself but on what the method does inside. They all have the same signature so an outside caller cannot even tell the difference.; When I call Test2() or Test3() and discard the return value, the task will still run. The delegate will run (maybe print to the console) and the file will be read.